# StartWithLetter and EndWithLetter in java

Tags: java

im doing a java activity that that if Name start with letter A-G and Ends with Letter H-z the output is invalid heres my code:

```
if(str.startsWith("a")){
System.out.print("Invalid Name! ");
}
if(str.endsWith("z")){
System.out.print("Invalid Name!");
}
```

Now How can i implment the alphabet letter a-g and h-z in if else Statement Thanks!

Comment: RegEx can help you out in a neat way. http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
if (str.matches("[a-gA-G].*[h-zH-Z]")) {
   System.out.print("Invalid Name! ");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `||`, if it were `&&` you could use one regex.

Comment: sir when i try to put my name that start me letter G it print nothing.

Comment: Do you want both conditions to be met or _either_?

Comment: The "^" at the start and "$" at the end is implied for `matches()`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ASCII value here.  A-Z  ranges from 65 to 90 ( for uppercase). 
I have used the hardcoded value here, straight from ASCII table just to introduce concept to you
Sample code :

```
String strUpperCase=str.toUpperCase();

    char start=str.charAt(0);
    char end=str.charAt(strUpperCase.length()-1);

    if((start>=65 && start<=71) || (end>=72 && end<=90)){
        System.out.println("Invalid name");
    }
```